# Specify width or height as percentages (%) in jquery options?

Tags: jquery, width

Quick question: When specifying options for a plugin, is it possible to use percentages (%) for specifying width or height?

Like in this example:

```
var options = $.extend( {
   width: 300,
   height: 200
  }
```

It doesn't seem to allow for % to be added for specifying width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strings for the value..

```
var options = $.extend( {
   width: '300%',
   height: '200%'
  }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work - seems to still take it as 300px for the width

Answer (score 0):

> .width( value ): **value** An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer along with
>   an optional unit of measure appended (as a string).

Source: [jQuery .width( value )](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2), so in your case:

```
var options = $.extend( {
   width: '300%',
   height: '200%'
}
```

Comment: thanks to you also, Sascha - but I couldn't give the correct answer to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use percentages or any units, you have to put the values in quotes.  If you don't it's not legal javascript syntax.  You're also missing a closing parenthesis and semicolon.

```
var options = $.extend( {
   width: '300%',
   height: '200%'
});
```

Comment: thank you for the syntax correction, and the right answer too